# ¿Las tres frases más largas de un array?

Tags: java

Buenas tardes y felices fiestas:
Me preguntaba de qué manera podría saber las tres frases más largas de un array de string.
Algo parecido al ejemplo:

```
String[]frasesPosibles={"Grandes esperanzas es una novela escrita por Charles Dickens","Fue publicada como serie",", desde el 1 de diciembre de 1860 hasta agosto de 1861,","en la revista literaria All the Year Round,","que habia sido fundada por el propio Dickens el anyo anterior."}​;
```

De momento lo que he hecho ha sido lo siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < frasesPosibles.length; i++) {

            if (frasesPosibles[i].length() > fraseLarga1) {
                masLarga1 = frasesPosibles[i];

            }

        }
        System.out.println("La frase más larga es: " + masLarga1);
```

El problema viene a la hora de sacar las otras dos, supongo que tengo que idear algún sistema para que la 1 pase a ser la 2 y la 2 la 3 hasta que termine el bucle, pero no se me ocurre nada.

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado para poderte ayudar

Comment: Puedes usar un array auxiliar de largo 3 donde vas metiendo las frases más largas, por ejemplo. Otra opción muy buena sería que ordenes el array según la longitud de las frases y entonces cojas las 3 primeras (o 3 últimas, según cómo lo ordenes)

Comment: recuerda aceptar la respuesta que te sirivio.. por favor, hace el [tour]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todas las respuestas son interesantes... pero en realidad pierden muchisimo tiempo ordenando un array que no necesita ser ordenado.

Ya que tu ejercicio habla de las 3 frases mayores, generemos 3 variables (podria ser tambien un array, una lista, o lo que gustes) y recorramos el array de frases una sola vez...

```
String[] frasesPosibles={"Grandes esperanzas es una novela escrita por Charles Dickens","Fue publicada como serie",", desde el 1 de diciembre de 1860 hasta agosto de 1861,","en la revista literaria All the Year Round,","que habia sido fundada por el propio Dickens el anyo anterior."}​;

string frase1 = "";
string frase2 = "";
string frase3 = "";

for (int i = 0; i < frasesPosibles.length; i++) {
    if (frasesPosibles[i].length() > frase1.length() ) {
        frase3 = frase2;
        frase2 = frase1;
        frase1 = frasesPosibles[i];
    }
    else if (frasesPosibles[i].length() > frase2.length() ) {
        frase3 = frase2;
        frase2 = frasesPosibles[i];
    }
    else if (frasesPosibles[i].length() > frase3.length() ) {
        frase3 = frasesPosibles[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("La frase más larga es: " + frase1 );
System.out.println("La segunda frase más larga es: " + frase2 );
System.out.println("La tercera frase más larga es: " + frase3 );
```

Comment: Muy interesante tu solución, me gustó mucho la verdad, tienes mi voto

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Te voto también. En un principio tenía una idea parecida a la tuya pero intente ponerlo todo en un if y e ahi mi error.Muchas gracias!

Comment: A veces añadimos complejidad al código por intentar hacerlo "mejor" de manera totalmente innecesaria , cuando lo "mejor" es hacerlo de la manera más sencilla y rápida. Tiene mi +1, caballero

Answer (score 2):

```
int tmp = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < frases.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < frases.length - 1; j++)
    {
        if(frases[j].length < frases[j + 1].length)
        {
            tmp = frases[j];          
            frases[j] = frases[j + 1];
            frases[j + 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Primero ordenamos el arreglo de frases mediante el **método burbuja**, teniendo en cuenta la longitud de los elementos del arreglo, este se ordena de mayor a menor.

Una vez ordenado pues imprimimos las 3 primeras posiciones que son las que tienen la longitud más larga.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   System.out.println(frases[i]);
}
```

Para que aprendas un poquito más puedes buscar en internet más información sobre el **método burbuja** y otros métodos de ordenamiento que son muchísimos.

Comment: Hacer los ejercicios de clase de alguien no está muy bien visto... ni siquiera ha intentado hacer nada todavía para sacar más de una, y ya le has dado el código para que copie y pegue. Qué va a aprender así?

Comment: Muchas gracias! No había pensado en el método de la burbuja pero en este caso es muy útil.

Comment: @Benito-B me parece que estas confundido, el usuario si puso lo que hizo, de hecho fui yo quien le pidió que lo pusiera, así que tu voto fue sumamente injusto, espero por favor rectifique tu posicion

Comment: @Benito-B me parece que tu voto fue basado en una apreciación personal equivocada

Comment: Votado quedas, pero al tener menos de 15 de reputación no se hace pública...Supongo que cuando suba ya irá apareciendo o algo. Siento los inconvenientes ocasionados pero llevo un par de días por aquí . Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: @Benito-B y acaso tu opinion sirve para decidir lo que es correcto o no lo es, mejor dejemoslo aqui, por cierto varios miembros con mayor reputacion que la tuya y la mia no estuvieron de acuerdo con tu actitud

Comment: @Japv te recomiendo que dejes los comentarios para lo que son, comentar cosas relacionadas con la pregunta/respuesta y no para rencillas personales, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

    String[] frasesPosibles = {
            "Grandes esperanzas es una novela escrita por Charles Dickens",
            "Fue publicada como serie",
            "desde el 1 de diciembre de 1860 hasta agosto de 1861",
            "en la revista literaria All the Year Round",
            "que habia sido fundada por el propio Dickens el anyo anterior."};

    public Main() {
        String[] newArray = Arrays.stream(frasesPosibles).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).limit(3).toArray(String[]::new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

No sé qué tal se te dé la programación funcional en Java, pero puedes probar esto.

Te explico un poco por encima qué hace la línea:

```
        String[] newArray = Arrays.stream(frasesPosibles).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).limit(3).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Primero convierte el array en un Stream, luego ordena dicho stream de forma inversa (en este caso de mayor a menor) y luego limita a 3 el número de items en el Stream ordenado, por último, retorna un array con los tres elementos.

Comment: Hacer los ejercicios de clase de alguien no está muy bien visto... ni siquiera ha intentado hacer nada todavía para sacar más de una, y ya le has dado el código para que copie y pegue. Qué va a aprender así?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Lo pruebo!

Answer (score 0):

Tomando el arreglo de la pregunta, tenemos 5 elementos:

```
String[] frasesPosibles={
    "Grandes esperanzas es una novela escrita por Charles Dickens",
    "Fue publicada como serie",
    ", desde el 1 de diciembre de 1860 hasta agosto de 1861,",
    "en la revista literaria All the Year Round,",
    "que habia sido fundada por el propio Dickens el anyo anterior."
}​;
```

Lo que puedes hacer es ordenar el arreglo de mayor a menor longitud, de manera que los tres primeros elementos son las frases más largas. Para ello, debes implementar la ordenación de burbuja mediante dos ciclos for. Dejo código

```
String aux; // Variable que ayudará al intercambio de posición de elementos en el método de burbuja  
for (int i = 0; i < frasesPosibles.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < frasesPosibles.length; j++) {
        // Si la longitud del elemento de la izquierda es menor a la longitud del elemento de la derecha, deben intercambiar posiciones.
        if (frasesPosibles[i].length() < frasesPosibles[j].length()) {
            aux = frasesPosibles[i];
            frasesPosibles[i] = frasesPosibles[j];
            frasesPosibles[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Las posibles frases quedarán ordenadas así

- que había sido fundada por el propio Dickens el anyo anterior.
- Grandes esperanzas es una novela escrita por Charles Dickens
- , desde el 1 de diciembre de 1860 hasta agosto de 1861,
- en la revista literaria All the Year Round,
- Fue publicada como serie